# C# Get file size

Tags: c#, file

**Problem:** I want to get file size, but file does not have extension example **testfile.txt** is normal file, here is example(without quotes) "**testfile**", also I have files which dont have extension but have spaces in name example(without quotes) "**my test file**", using **File.Exist** it reads as Folder, current function I using for file size

```
    using System.IO;
    static long GetFileSize(string FilePath)
    {
        if(File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            return new FileInfo(FilePath).Length;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Current Usage:

```
GetFileSize("C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Appdata\\Local\\Data Manager\\Super User\\User data controller");
```

And it throws error: **System.IO.IOException: 'The directory name is invalid**

File Does not Violate Invalid Path Char rules, path only contains numbers, letter and/or spaces.

Application is launched AS Admin AND Visual Studio is Launched too As Admin

Full Error:

```
    System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x8007010B
  Message=The directory name is invalid.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()

   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)

   at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)

   at test.SuperUserControlEngine.GetFileSize(String FilePath)
   at test.systems.superuser.HoloPart.Control1.ControllerSize()
   at test.systems.superuser.HoloPart.Control1.GetAllControllersSize()
   at test.SuperUserControlEngine.ScanHolos()
   at test.ManagerEngine.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at test.App.Main()
```

Image:
[test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qtNd.png)

**Solution:** If someone could tell what I did wrong in my code and help it solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: _"using File.Exist it reads as Folder"_ - explain this. Your problem is unclear. `new FileInfo("C:\Temp\Some file with spaces but without extension")` works just fine.

Comment: Also the current snippet won't even build, it's got a syntax error but I presume it's just a typo.

Comment: for me it throws error: System.IO.IOException: 'The directory name is invalid and C:\Users\TestUser\Appdata\Local\Data Manager\Super User\User data controller < User data controller is file not folder.

Comment: For which path?

Comment: @itsme86 I posted above my example

Comment: There are a bunch of illegal path characters (see `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` and `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars`).  There are also format issues - for example, a colon(`:`) is only valid as the second character in a path (but not a file name).  As @itsme86 says, what exactly is the value of `FilePath`.  If it looks reasonable, look a the individual characters and make sure you don't have any funky (but not necessarily visible) characters in it

Comment: @Flydog57  "C:\Users\TestUser\Appdata\Local\Data Manager\Super User\User data controller" < User data controller is file not folder. And File does not violate any invalid path char rules, name contains only letters and numbers and spaces.

Comment: So, your code looks like `var path = "C:\Users\TestUser\Appdata\Local\Data Manager\Super User\User data controller"; var result = GetFileSize(path);` with the function above.  And, there's a file named `"User data controller"` in a folder named `"C:\Users\TestUser\Appdata\Local\Data Manager\Super User"`.  Is that right?  You should add that to your question.  Along with the *exact* (i.e., copy/pasted) wording of the exception message.

Comment: Yes! And It throws error System.IO.IOException: 'The directory name is invalid

Comment: So the exception message is `"'The directory name is invalid"`, not `"The directory name is invalid and C:\Users\TestUser\Appdata\Local\Data Manager\Super User\User data controller < User data controller is file not folder."`

Comment: Yes, so it could be wrong path? but if i copy-paste in explorer it opens just fine.

Comment: What? Opens with what?! Windows needs a file type to determine which program to open the file in. Since your file has no extension, how is it opening the file?

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as admin?  It could be a permission issue. Reading paths to other user's files, usually requires elevated permissions.

Comment: Your problem is in no way reproducible. At least include [the full exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) so that we might get an idea about what's going on.

Comment: Have a look at this https://superuser.com/q/432980/615931

Comment: In the `Super User` folder, what does the icon next to `User data controller` look like?  Is it a yellow folder icon or does it look like a white piece of paper with the top-right corner folded down

Comment: @Flydog57 white piece of paper with the top-right corner folded down

Comment: show us a screenshot from that directory in Windows Explorer. It is hard to believe that this is failing. people use this all the time. This way we can further help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your permission to the folder first. If you don't have permission to the folder, then the file operation won't work:

```
using System.IO;
static long GetFileSize(string FilePath)
{
    //if you don't have permission to the folder, Directory.Exists will return False
    if(!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath))
    {
        //if you land here, it means you don't have permission to the folder
        Debug.Write("Permission denied");
        return -1;
    }
    else if(File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        return new FileInfo(FilePath).Length;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Read more: [Read Permissions to a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2274724/283895)

Comment: Weird, after inserting your code it does not throw any error, codes seems working fine AND Debug is empty, meaning it does not output Permision denied message.

Comment: ACL and permissions can cause some frustrating and misleading behavior sometimes.

Comment: Another example for you: copy that same file into your c:\user\[my login]\appdata\local\ folder.  The code should work in its original form (before my code change).  The problem was permissions and not really about the path, like the error suggested.

Comment: Well I mark this as answer, since issue is solved. Congrats mate.

Comment: I had this as possibility since default path is hidden, but I could still access this path so I declined as possibility